# Disqus authentication doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, comments

Disqus authentication doesn't work in Chrome on all sites.
It doesn't work for all auth methods and on different computers.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Doesn't work"? What happens when you try?

Comment: This sounds like a profile setting that is preventing it.  I have verified that Disqus has no problems authenticating on my test machine.

Comment: When I try to login, the page refreshes, but nothing happens.

Comment: I log out and reset Chrome settings, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably have disbled 3rd party cookies.

Go to settings, search for 'cookies', Content Settings, uncheck block third party cookies